# Inner Product of Bounded Self Adjoint Linear Operator

Tags: normed-spaces, linear-transformations, inner-products, supremum-and-infimum, adjoint-operators

$T:V \rightarrow V$ is a bounded self adjoint linear operator, where $V$ is an inner product space.

**Why is:**

$|<Tv,v>| \leq M \cdot ||v||^2 $

for all $v \in V$, where $M=sup_{||x||=1} \{\mid <Tx,x>\mid \}$

Comment: Use \langle and \rangle for your inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$

Comment: oh makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $v \neq 0$, we have
$$
|\langle Tv,v \rangle| = 
\|v\|^2 \left \langle T\frac{v}{\|v\|},\frac{v}{\|v\|}\right \rangle \leq \|v\|^2 \cdot M
$$